# compare dateofbirth to the current date in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

```
$this->set('one',$this->Profile->find('all',array(
            'conditions'=>array('MONTH(Profile.DOB)'=>'MONTH(CURDATE())','DAY(Profile.DOB)>='=>'DAY(CURDATE())'),
            'order'=>'MONTH(Profile.DOB),DAY(Profile.DOB)'
            )));
```

can anyone help me in this please.... actually I need to display the date of birth comparing with the current date...

Comment: Comparing how? What do you want the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

By the logic of it, are you trying to find upcoming birthdays for current month? If so, you should check the [CakeTime Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html), it has useful functions. In this case you can make a combination of isThisMonth with isToday and isFuture.

Answer (score 0):

how about

'conditions'=>
   array(
        'MONTH(Profile.DOB)' => date('m'),
        'DAY(Profile.DOB) >= '=> date('d'),
)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to 'find' dates that match the current day, you could use the following condition in your find. ( I try and omit using SQL's NOW() function so it does not conflict with the Database servers timezone setting VS the application servers timezone settings IE: Amazon RDS )

```
$find = $this->Model->find('all',array(
     'conditions'=>array(
         'DATE(Model.DOB)' => date('Y-m-d')
     )
));
```